# Google Sheets - IF Statement Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to write a formula that enters 'Y' if the patient is up to date with their immunizations based on their record and age, and 'N' if they are not. Age (D$) is in months and I have a column for every immunization (8 weeks(E$), 12 weeks(F$), 16 weeks(G$), 1 year(H$), 3 years and 4 months(I$)) which is marked as either ("Y" or colored Grey) as well as a final column which the formula is being entered into(J$). Any ideas what formula I need to use?

So far I have been thinking to use an IFS statement { =IFS(D$>=2, AND(E$="Y"),"Y")}. Although I can see the limitations to using this.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1):

For every immunization, the patient is not up to date if *the corresponding cell is blank* **and** *their age is older than the immunization date*. You want to check this for multiple immunizations. You can use `COUNTIFS` to evaluate two (or more) conditions.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(E3:I3,"",E$1:I$1,"<="&D3)>0,"N","Y")
```

Explanation:
`COUNTIFS` returns the number of shots for which the patient is not up to date.
`IF` returns N if the previous value is greater than 0, Y otherwise.

Note that I'm assuming the information on the number of months corresponding to each immunization (`E$1:I$1` in the formula above) is present somewhere in the sheet or that you can add it. If this is not the case, you would indeed need to use `IFS` or something similar.